# Python logging issue?

Tags: python, logging

I am writing the below code to log messages into a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import logging 

## init logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

## create handler file
handler = logging.FileHandler('mylog3.log')

## set log level
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

## add handler to logger
logger.addHandler(handler)

l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
i = 3

logger.info('This is an info message')
logger.warning('This is a warning message')
logger.debug('This is a debug message.  I=%d l=%s', i, l)
logger.error('This is an error message. l =%s', l)
logger.fatal('This is a fatal error message')
```

The problem I am seeing is that no matter what setting I give, it always prints the warning, error and fatal error messages in file.   The debug and info messages are never written.

I verified that I am seeing the issue w/ both PyCharm on Windows and also on my Ubuntu linux Python 3.  So, it must be that I am doing something wrong.  What can it be?   I am at a loss!

Comment: If I've answered your question, please mark my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both loggers and handlers have levels. You've set the level for the handler, but not for the logger - and that defaults to `WARNING`. If you do e.g. `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`, you should see `DEBUG` and `INFO` messages as well (if you don't set a level on the handler at all) or `INFO` messages but not `DEBUG` messages (if you set the handler's level to `logging.INFO`).

See [this diagram](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-flow) for more info on the information flow in logging.

Comment: Thank you for making it clear. It now works as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

The debug and info messages are not shown because of the line `handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)`. This causes all messages of level `logging.INFO` or less (only info and debug) to not be shown. You can replace `loggign.INFO` with `logging.NOTSET` to fix this.

Comment: Even if I removed the line, it prints only the warning and error messages.

Comment: @whirlaway The default level is `WARNING`.

Comment: Removing `handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)` does not fix it.